# Moving objects to mouseclick position java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm fairly new to programming. I'm trying to figure out how to move an object to the position where my mouse clicks within a panel. The object can be represented as a shape like a circle and is initialized at the top left corner of the panel. When I click, I don't want it to teleport to the position of where my mouse clicks but rather move there smoothly. How do I do that?

Comment: *but rather move there smoothly* - use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to animate the motion.

Comment: Thanks. I used Swing Timer and it worked.